# NewDocumentCommand with an alternative to s

Tags: xparse

I'd like to make a `\NewDocumentCommand` using the `s` argument, but with `+` or `-` or ... instead of `*` and then be able to test witch  special character was used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{%
    s}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    with boolean
    % here I'd like to test witch special character wos used
    }{%
    without boolean}%
    }

\begin{document}

\foo    % works

\foo*   % works

\foo+   % doesn't work, but I would like ;-)

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{st+t-}{\IfBooleanT{#1}{star}\IfBooleanT{#2}{plus}\IfBooleanT{#3}{minus}}`

Comment: Thank you. Is there the only way ? What if there is other arguments and on wants to add new special character ?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment...? You can test for a token with the `t` argument. Every test counts as a new argument...

Comment: @cgnieder My point is, if there is first 2 booleans, the fisrt mandatory is #3, if I will add (an hypothetic update) a third boolean, the first madatory argument shift and others too. I asked for a mathode where all the booleans are #1 and the I test #1. If it is not possible, your answers fits me. You can write it and I'll accepte it. Thanks.

Comment: Everything is possible :) Your requirement could be achieved using two macros where the first tests for tokens and sets some flags, say, and then calls the second macro with the normal mandatory macros.

Comment: @jon `\IfBoolean(TF)` is documented!

Comment: Something like `\def\barf#1{%
  \def\tempa{*}\def\tempb{+}\def\tempc{-}%
  \if#1\tempa
 star
  \else\if#1\tempb plus
  \else\if#1\tempc minus
  \fi\fi\fi
  \foo}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{%
 do whatever}
`?

Comment: This is something that has passed through my mind before, it would be nice if there's an official solution, something like `\NewDocumentCommand\foo{ T m }{\IfCase{#1}{{*}{it was an asterisk} {+}{it was a plus} {-}{..}}}`. It's true that many times you don't need three optional tokens, `s t+ t-`, but one, and check which one was used is. (some sort of `O{default}` or `D(){default}` but with no delimiters, `T{+}`? I don't know.)

Comment: @Manuel There is a parameter `l` I didn't notice before. It can be used in this case. See my answer.

Comment: @Tarass You should always consider the user, when defining a macro; if a variant character is expected, it should be in a well defined list, otherwise it is a regular argument. The interface has already be shown by cgnieder.

Comment: @egreg I agree with you. See the edit of the answer and my last.

Comment: @JosephWright -- Oh, `\IfBoolean(TF)` means that there's a `\IfBooleanF` and `\IfBooleanT`?  That was not immediately clear to me from the `xparse` docs (I did wonder about the use of parentheses, but I did not explore), though I can see that I should've made the inference from the discussion about `\IfNoValue(TF)`.  What's the difference between `\IfBooleanTF` and `\IfBooleanT`?

Comment: @jon `T` represents True, and `F` represents False. They have only the branches in the name, here is an example of the syntax: `\IfBooleanTF{#1}{in case it's true}{in case it's false}`, `\IfBooleanT{#1}{in case it's true}`, `\IfBooleanF{#1}{in case it's false}`.

Comment: @Manuel -- Thanks for the explanation: I have no time to fiddle these days (though I did know what the T and F stood for).  Anyway, wish I'd known this sooner! So many macros would've been written differently....  (I also realize I could've inferred it from the xparse docs, but I still think an explicit documentation of the commands along the lines of the `\IfNoValue(TF)` section wouldn't hurt for people -- like me -- who are too obtuse to make the leap on their own.)

Comment: @jon It comes (I think, as an outside opinion which is not involved) from the expl3 true and false conditionals, e.g., there are three kind of most conditionals `\cs_if_exist:NTF \cs {true} {false}`, `\cs_if_exist:NT \cs {true}` and `\cs_if_exist:NF \cs {false}`.

Comment: @Manuel -- Ah, OK.  I hope to have time to explore further.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think another approach *might* be better.
Added some control on the first boolean, and `No-Value`-like error messages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,ifthen,xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{%
    lm}{%

\StrLen{#1}[\L]%
\ifthenelse{\L>1}{-- \#1 Too long ! -- }{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{It's empty ! }{
        \StrPosition{*+-}{#1}[\L]%
        \ifthenelse{\L=0}{-- \#1 Forbiden boolean ! -- }{%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{*}}{It's a star !}{}%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{-}}{It's a minus !}{}%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{+}}{It's a plus !}{}
        }%
    }%
}%
#2 -- #1
}

\begin{document}

\foo{bob}   % works
\foo*{bob}  % works
\foo+{bob}  % works
\foo-{bob}  % works
\foo!{bob}  % works
\foo*!{bob} % works
\foo!!{bob} % works

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't remember this `l` argument. Still, it's not perfect, for instance, if you want an optional argument before the mandatory one.

Comment: I beg to differ with your opinion.

Comment: @cgnieder It's a banal syntax error, try any command with a star if it hasn't one. One can filter this case by `\ifx#1 you stutter \else ...` ;-)

Comment: I agree with you. I was lazzy and didn't use the `ifthen` package. Still, the `l` parameter type save the situation until `xparse` gives a proper solution. One can imagine that `s` parameter type could have optional argument such as `s[+-/]` then one can remplace the star by any character in the list.

Comment: Sorry, even after the edit, this is not what I'd consider a sound user interface. The purpose of the `l` argument type is very different.

Comment: @egreg What is the intended use of `l`? (And why shouldn't it be used differently?)

Comment: @cfr It's used for grabbing whatever is between the macro and the first open brace, in order to be examined later. The usage is rather technical, but usually not limited to a single token for defining variants.